# Comparing two custom classes

Tags: c#, equality

I'm trying to compare two objects I've created.
In some other posts, the class needs to inherit from the `IEquatable<T>` interface and then override the `Equals` function. When I compare the instances of the class, with `cellStyle1.Equals(cellStyle2)`, it always returns `false`...

I've tried it and it doesn't seem to work. Here's what I tried:

```
class Cell_Style: IEquatable<Cell_Style>
{
    private Color cellColor;
    private Color fontColor;
    private int fontSize;
    private bool underline;
    private bool bold;
    private bool italic;

    public int FontSize { get => fontSize; set => fontSize = value; }
    public Color FontColor { get => fontColor; set => fontColor = value; }
    public Color CellColor { get => cellColor; set => cellColor = value; }
    public bool Underline { get => underline; set => underline = value; }
    public bool Bold { get => bold; set => bold = value; }
    public bool Italic { get => italic; set => italic = value; }

    public Cell_Style(Excel.Range cell)
    {
        cellColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(Convert.ToInt32(cell.Interior.Color));
        underline = (cell.Font.Underline == (int)Excel.XlUnderlineStyle.xlUnderlineStyleSingle) ? true : false;
        bold = cell.Font.Bold;
        fontColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(Convert.ToInt32(cell.Font.Color));
        fontSize = Convert.ToInt32(cell.Font.Size);
        italic = cell.Font.Italic;
    }

    //1st attempt
    bool IEquatable<Cell_Style>.Equals(Cell_Style other) 
    {
        return Equals(other);
    }

    //2nd attempt
    bool IEquatable<Cell_Style>.Equals(Cell_Style other) 
    {
        if (other.Bold == bold &&
            other.CellColor == cellColor &&
            other.FontColor == fontColor &&
            other.FontSize == fontSize &&
            other.Underline == underline && 
            other.Italic == italic)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: didn't  yo try debugging it ?

Comment: i used `messagebox.show(...)` to visually compare several instances and get the return result. Going to try to debug

Comment: try to debug the second attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implementing `IEquatable<Cell_Style>` explicitly so you need to cast to that interface before calling it:

```
((IEquatable<Cell_Style>)cellStyle1).Equals(cellStyle2)
```

a simpler approach would be to make the implementation public:

```
public bool Equals(Cell_Style other) { ... }
```

then the correct overload of `Equals` will be chosen if `cellStyle2` has type `Cell_Style`. You should also override `object.Equals` to call `Equals(Cell_Style)` and implement `GetHashCode`.

Comment: i changed the signature to `public bool Equals(Cell_Style other) { ... }` and it works. What would be the use of overriding object.Equals?

Comment: @ElliottAddi - If you're defining equality for your class you should implement both overloads of `Equals` and ideally `GetHashCode` as well. Consumers would be surprised by a difference between `cellStyle1.Equals(cellStyle2)` and `cellStyle1.Equals((object)cellStyle2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You call `Equals` method which is inherited from `System.Object` instead of your implementation. You should override base `Equals` method and it's better to use implicit interface implementation (instead of explicit) so your method will be called directly if compiler can resolve this call (`cellStyle1` and `cellStyle2` are both of `Cell_Style` type at compile time).

Comment: Thank you! unfortunatly, can't put 2 answers :/